# Solidity : Problem to display value from my smart contract to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity

I have method "cote" in my solidity file

app.sol :

```
function cote() public view returns (uint256){
        return data;
        
    }
```

App.js :

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
          web3: '',
          Amount: '',
          cote: '',
          InputAmount: '',
          weiConversion : 1000000000000000000
        }

    getCote(){
            const contract = require('truffle-contract');
            const Betting = contract(BettingContract);
            Betting.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider);
            var BettingInstance;
            this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
                Betting.deployed().then((instance) => {
                  BettingInstance = instance
                }).then((result) => {
                  return BettingInstance.cote.call({from: accounts[0]})
                }).then((result) => {
                  this.setState({
                    cote : result.c
                  })
                }).catch(() => {
                  console.log("Error with cote")
                })
              })
          }
```

I store the value in my cote variable.

When I try to display `<h5>Data : {this.state.cote} </h5>` this value I have always the error : `"Error with cote"` Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Just change BettingInstance.cote.call({from: accounts[0]})
to BettingInstance.cote().call({from: accounts[0]})